# Finding unknown variable.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Here is a question I came across on this [website for interview questions](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/myntra-interview-experience-set-3-campus/). PI Round 2 Puzzle.

Two boys $A$ and $B$ enter a tunnel. At $\dfrac{2}{3}$ of the tunnel,they see a train coming towards the tunnel, the train is still at a distance from the tunnel. $A$ runs back to that end of the tunnel from which they entered the tunnel, $B$ runs towards the other end of the tunnel. Both of them just make it without being run over by the train. The train is travelling at a speed of $60$kmph. Find the length of the tunnel.

Now I have worked out by assuming the length of tunnel to be $x$ that time taken by train to  cross tunnel will be $\dfrac{3x}{50}$sec. Problem is there is need for one more parameter either time taken by $A$ to reach other end or something else which is absent in the question.

Is there any way this question can be solved without additional information?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/771544/a-logic-problem-which-involves-math looks like the same puzzle, but with $3/8$ instead of $2/3$.

Comment: I would say scenario is similar except that in this question we have to calculate length of tunnel and speed of train is given. I checked that question before, but situation here is different.

Answer (score 0):

How did you get $3x/50 sec$?

But you are right, you'd need an additional information:

Let $x$ be the length of the tunnel. When they see the train coming they both run $1/3$ of the length of the tunnel untill the train enters the tunnel. That means the train takes the same amount of time for crossing the whole tunnel $x$ as it takes boy $A$ to run the remaining third. Let us assume it takes each of the boy $s$ hours of time to run one third of the tunnel. Then $x = s\cdot 60km/h$. It is obvious that you cannot calculate $x$ without having $s$, which is unknown.

Comment: To be noticed that speed of train is given in _km/h_. I just converted it to _m/s_. So it comes out to be _(50/3)m/s_. I would like to keep it in fraction as it would facilitate calculations.